# Laravel trying to store image file in 3 different folder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-controller, laravel-10

I'm trying to store image in 3 different folder inside public folder now I'm able to store in two different folder but when I added 3rd folder path but it was not coping in 3rd folder help me to solve this.

**my two folder copying Working code**

```
$input['student_photo'] = time().'.'.$request->student_photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $folder1 = public_path('public/path1/');
    $path1 = $folder1 . $input['student_photo']; // path 1
    $request->student_photo->move($folder1, $input['student_photo']); // image saved in first folder
    $path2 = public_path('public/path2/') . $input['student_photo']; // path 2
    \File::copy($path1, $path2);
```

**I tired this code for copy 3rd folder but not working**

```
$input['student_photo'] = time().'.'.$request->student_photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $folder1 = public_path('public/path1/');
    $path1 = $folder1 . $input['student_photo']; // path 1
    $request->student_photo->move($folder1, $input['student_photo']); // image saved in first folder
    $path2 = public_path('public/path2/') . $input['student_photo']; // path 2
    $path3 = public_path('public/path3/') . $input['student_photo']; // path 3
    \File::copy($path1, $path2, $path3);
```

Comment: What errors does it give? What are the permissions on all folders?

Comment: @Sergey Makarov i dont get any error but 3rd path folder dont get any image if i check

Comment: I think it should be \File::copy($path1, $path2); \File::copy($path1, $path3);

Comment: @Sergey Makarov yes working thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\File::copy($path1, $path2); 
\File::copy($path1, $path3);
```